# How to fil a ComboBox with MVVM Light binding and XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, combobox, mvvm-light

I have a list that with items that I want to show in a ComboBox, but the result is that I don't see the text but this:

```
 App1.Data.Models.Test
 App1.Data.Models.Test
 App1.Data.Models.Test
```

I don't really know how to show the proper text.

The model Test has 2 properties ID and Name.

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
           Grid.Row="3"
           Margin="10"
           ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}" />
```

Do I need to use DataTemplate like a ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the Property from`App1.Data.Models.Test` you want to display by `DisplayMemberPath`. 
Alternatively override `ToString()`

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
       Grid.Row="3"
       Margin="10"
       DisplayMemberPath = "Name"
       ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}" />
```

Comment: Ah yes indeed! And with SelectedItem you get the whole object back? ID and Name?

Comment: yes you do. Bind it to a property of Type App1.Data.Models.Test

Answer (score 2):

The `ComboBox` uses the `ToString()` method of its items to display them.

Either override `App1.Data.Models.Test.ToString()`, or choose a specific property of `App1.Data.Models.Test` to display, let's say `Name`:

```
<ComboBox
       Grid.Column="1"
       Grid.Row="3"
       Margin="10"
       ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}"
       DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: It says the property "Path" is set more then once.